# Serilog ThreadId is always output as 1

Tags: c#, logging, serilog-sinks-file

I have a ThreadId in the outputTemplate but the log always records it as 1. I have several instances of the app running at the same time into the same log and so was hoping I could separate the instances based on the ThreadId.

Can anyone suggest how to work around this? The ThreadName gets assigned after the app sets up a few things and identifies the area it is running in so is not the best seperator. Also there can be multiple functions run in an area concurrently. Hence the need for the ThreadId

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.WithThreadName()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] <{ThreadName}> <{ThreadId}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")      
            .WriteTo.File(@".\log\log.txt", 
                             rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, 
                             shared: true,
                             outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] <{ThreadName}> <{ThreadId}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Log output

```
2021-04-09 06:30:09.059 [INF] <blackstone> <1> Action : Task A
2021-04-09 06:30:09.059 [INF] <wavell> <1> Action : Task A
2021-04-09 06:30:09.060 [INF] <forest> <1> Action : Task A
2021-04-09 06:30:09.130 [INF] <wavell> <1> Loading CentreDetails
2021-04-09 06:30:09.130 [INF] <forest> <1> Loading CentreDetails
2021-04-09 06:30:09.132 [INF] <blackstone> <1> Loading CentreDetails
2021-04-09 06:30:09.560 [INF] <wavell> <1> Loading ParentDetails
2021-04-09 06:30:09.554 [INF] <blackstone> <1> Loading ParentDetails
2021-04-09 06:30:09.560 [INF] <forest> <1> Loading ParentDetails
```

Comment: What are instances in '*separate the instances*'?

Comment: If you add `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to your log messages what does it display?

Comment: @tymtam I want Serilog to put in it's pattern the Thread ID. Not explicitly log it each time I call Log.Information("Action : Task A").

Comment: Understood, I just wanted to see if the ids match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I follow what @Nicholas Blumhardt was aiming at...

Added the Serilog.Enrichers.Process nuget and updated the code to this

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                .Enrich.WithThreadName()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] <{ThreadName}> <{ProcessId}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")      
                .WriteTo.File(@".\log\log.txt", 
                                 rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, 
                                 shared: true,
                                 outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] <{ThreadName}> <{ProcessId}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
```

The log is now pushing out a unique Process ID

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me — it logs thread ids of currently running threads, not the one where Logger instance was created:

**nuget package**

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
```

**appsettings.json {ThreadId}**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "/log/api.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] Th:{ThreadId} {Message} {NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "acme"
    }
  }
}
```

**startup .Enrich.WithThreadId()**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).Enrich.WithThreadId()
        .CreateLogger();
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

**sample log**

```
2022-03-11 14:49:25.425 -05:00 [Information] Th:27 foo
2022-03-11 14:49:25.428 -05:00 [Information] Th:5 Bar
```

Comment: I confirm that it logs current thread ids (not the one where the logger was created). I used Nuget packages: Serilog 2.12.0, Serilog.Enrichers.Thread 3.1.0, Serilog.Sinks.File 5.0.0 with .Net Framework 4.8.
In my case I don't read configuration from json. I build it dynamically. `.Enrich.WithThreadId()` is required.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want [`Serilog.Enrichers.Process`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-process/#serilogenrichersprocess) and `Enrich.WithProcessId()` instead of `WithThreadId()`.

Comment: Serilog.Enrichers.Process nuget is already in the solution. I already have .Enrich.WithThreadId() in the LoggerConfiguration(). Do you have an example of what you mean?